# How to install framework (from pkg file) in a non-standard location?

Tags: macos, install, python, pkg

In brief, my question is this:

***How can I install a framework from a *.pkg file somewhere other than under `/Library/Frameworks` (or `/System/Library/Frameworks`)?***

---

**Background**

I want to install a version of Python 2.7.3 that lives under `$HOME/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and `$HOME/python`.

My goal here is to have a version of Python that is as independent as possible from the Python that comes with OS X Lion.  In particular, I want to have an installation of Python that is, as much as possible, not liable to be altered "behind-my-back" by system updates or other software updates.  That's why I want to keep this installation as clear as possible away from the "standard" places for them.

Among the problems I am trying to avoid by doing this is the [buggy Tk framework](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk) that comes with the latest versions of OS X.

Therefore, a key sub-goal here is to install new Tcl and Tk frameworks, separate from the system-supplied ones.  The ones I want to install come from [ActiveState ("Mac OS X (10.5+, x86_64/x86)")](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads), in the form of a *.pkg file.

When I click on this file, I get presented with the usual "wizard"-like sequence of steps ("Introduction", "License", etc.).  At no point during this sequence I am offered the opportunity to choose a different installation location for these frameworks before I reach the choice of clicking on the <kbd>INSTALL</kbd> button.<sup>1</sup>

I suspect that if I click on this button, the installed files will go under `/Library/Frameworks` (or possibly under `/System/Library/Frameworks`), which is what I'm trying to avoid.  (Indeed, when I click on <kbd>INSTALL</kbd>, I'm immediately presented with an password-entry dialog, which is a pretty good indication that the installation will put files somewhere under `/Library` or `/System`.)

Therefore I'm looking for an alternative way to perform this installation that will allow me to *explicitly set* the destination folder for the installed files.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Yes, the installer allows me choose a different volume for the installation, but it does not let me specify, e.g., `$HOME/Library/Frameworks` as the destination for the installed files.</sub>

Comment: System updates will only update the Apple supplied python, any other python will be separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, **you can only relocate a package** (that is, install it into a different directory) **that has been built with relocation in mind**.

If the package supports it, it can be relocated with the command line equivalent of `Installer.app`, conveniently called `installer`, with option `-target` (from `man installer`):

> The target volume is specified with the `-target` parameter (`-tgt` is
>   accepted as a synonym).

The argument to `-target` is:

1. A volume mount point (`/Volumes/HDD`), device node (`/dev/disk0s5`) or volume UUID (`376C4046-083E-334F-AF08-62FAFBC4E352`), for example:

   ```
   installer -pkg InstallMe.pkg -target /
   ```
2. Any of the values returned by `-dominfo` (`LocalSystem` or `CurrentUserHomeDirectory`), for example:

   ```
   installer -pkg InstallMe.pkg -target CurrentUserHomeDirectory
   ```

(As you see, the latter command looks very promising. It would install `InstallMe.pkg` in the hierarchy of the home directory of the current user.)

In our specific case, unfortunately, **ActiveState's Tcl package wasn't designed to be relocated**:

- It doesn't return any information for `-dominfo`:

  ```
  $ installer -verbose -dominfo -pkg ActiveTcl-8.6.pkg
  Domain information:
  NoDomainsAvailable
  ```
- Although the `pkg` file can be successfully installed on another volume:

  ```
  $ sudo installer -verbose -pkg ActiveTcl-8.6.pkg -target /Volumes/DISK2GO/
  installer: Package name is ActiveState ActiveTcl 8.6.0.0.296563
  installer: Installing at base path /Volumes/DISK2GO
  (...)   
  #
  installer: Writing files….....
  (...)
  installer: The software was successfully installed......
  installer: The install was successful.
  #
  ```

  as can be seen here:

  [image]

  it doesn't work:

  ```
  $ cd /Volumes/DISK2GO/usr/local/bin/
  $ ./tclsh8.6
  dyld: Library not loaded:
  /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/Tcl
    Referenced from: /Volumes/DISK2GO/usr/local/bin/./tclsh8.6
    Reason: image not found
  Trace/BPT trap: 5
  $  ./tclselect 
  -bash: ./tclselect: /usr/local/bin/tclsh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
  ```

The reason is that scripts and compiled tools use and are linked to `/Library/Frameworks`:

```
$ cd /Volumes/DISK2GO/usr/local/bin/
$ otool -L tclsh8.6 
 tclsh8.6:
 /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/Tcl (compatibility version 8.6.0, current version 8.6.0)
(...)
$ grep Library tclselect 
#  /Library/Frameworks
# installation. I.e. a Tcl installed in '/Library/Frameworks' and
return /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions
```

If you wish to use ActiveState's Tcl you must install the package in its default location.

And as far as I can tell, **it won't conflict with the installed Tcl framework**:

- OS X own framework is installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/`, some binaries in `/usr/bin`.
- ActiveState's Tcl installs in `/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework`, `/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework`, `/Library/Tcl` and `/usr/local/bin` (for a full listing, double click the `pkg` file and select File>ShowFiles).

Answer (score 2):

You can safely install Python under `/Library/Frameworks` and not worry about it interfering with the "system" Python, although with a few symlinks and/or `$PATH` changes you can make it the default if you want.

As an alternative, you can install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) and set its install root to whatever you want (the default is `/opt/local`, I believe, although this is configurable during setup), although the Python framework will still be installed under a `Library/Frameworks` subdirectory. I prefer the MacPorts distribution over the [python.org](http://www.python.org) one because there are many additional modules you can install which are pre-configured to build correctly, which isn't always the case when you use `pip` or `easy_install`, depending on what you're trying to build. MacPorts also has a pretty decent versioning system, allowing multiple versions to coexist side-by-side, with simple tools to switch between them. As an added bonus, the MacPorts Tcl is not "broken," so everything *should* work out of the box. YMMV :)